Why would a depletion "layer" form in a PN junction?
I understand that electrons diffuse from the N to the P region due to the concentration difference. This diffusion of electrons creates an electric field opposing further diffusion.
What I don't understand is why diffused electrons form a layer? Shouldn't they be spread across the whole P-region?
If I assume it's because of electrical stability of the recombined atoms, it still should spread, as neighbouring atoms should also have the same level of stability.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry, typo. Is it correct now?

The moment it goes from the N side to the P side, it will both see an electric field pushing it back towards the N side and also contribute to making that electric field stronger. So it cannot be spread across the whole P region. In fact, at thermal equilibrium, this electric field would be spread throughout the entire depletion region, i.e. before it even gets to the boundary, it would already see this electric field.

This confusion is one reason why both minority and majority carriers, and generation/recombination need to be taken into account. Those electrons don’t form a layer, they recombine.

Sorry if I misunderstood. I don't get what you are saying. According to my understanding, if electron build up at depletion layer then the voltage difference between that area and whole P side would cause electron to move across whole P side to equalise voltage. I hope you understand what I am saying.

I found the answer (at least I have a theory). The electrons from N-type (that are now in P-type) are attracted by the positively-charged N-type. This builds up electrons at their barrier (depletion layer), where electrons stay close to N-type due to attractive force. Vice versa, the same thing happens in P-type.
(This is just an idea that felt logical to me. Please do point issues in my theory or provide an better one.)
